# How can i implement dictionary with translations

Tags: iphone, database, ios, sqlite

I want to create a Eng<->Rus dictionary application. As far as I know, I need to use SQLite. But how can I implement the translation function? How can I find corresponding translation of the word requested by the user? Any help, guidance, tutorials will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of (ie.) russian words mapping to an english word? Or are you trying to be smart about word sense disambiguation, for instance?

Comment: no, i'm just trying to figure out how to map english words to it's russian translations in a big database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeDict has a good collection of bilingual dictionaries, including eng-rus. It's under GPL.

If you need only eng->rus translation, this is basically a hashtable, where the english word is the key, and the list of corresponding russian words are the value.

If you need bidirectional translation, I would store each word as follows:

> [word], [language], [set of corresponding translations]

The translation is easy then: you lookup the word W in language L, and return the set of possible translations.

You may want to have a look here too [How do I initialize a store with default data in a CoreData application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264382/how-do-i-initialize-a-store-with-default-data-in-a-coredata-application)

Also, it's probably a good thing to add some non-aggressive [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and/or normalization, so that if I search for a plural (ie. eggs) it's resolved to the singular, or if I search a specific verbal form (ie. walking) it's resolved to the verb's infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a lot of ways you could achieve this, but at the simplest level, consider using paired-arrays....two separate arrays. One contains English words, the second array containing the translated equivalents. You can then request a given term at a specified index, and access both terms for it.

In CoreData, you could specify a "Word" entity, with attributes of "English" and "Russian".