# Creating default data for an entity in CoreData (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want my app to have some default data so the user isn't presented with an empty tableView. 
The data needs to be on coreData, and then fetched and put onto the the tableView.

At the moment, the user can add some data, delete it and edit it, but when they first open the app there isn't any data, which doesn't look great and might confuse the user.

The default data should be deletable and editable like the rest of the data, so it can't be "false data", like strings stored in an array.

How can I add some default data using Swift?

Comment: You can not have default entries in Core data, if you want you may fill core data programatically.

Comment: or you may go with plist to store static info.

Comment: Best solution for you to store data in .plist file

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264382/how-do-i-initialize-a-store-with-default-data-in-a-coredata-application.

Answer (score 0):

The cellforRowatindexpath method defines the cell for your table. If you want some default cells you can define them there. Either create some custom cells with false data, or (this is better) define an array or dictionary in your tableView class with false data, and use it to feed your table's delegate and datasource methods (numberOfRows/numberOfSections need input, as well). Basic example:

```
CustomUIViewController : UIViewController {
    let defaults : [String] = ["Some", "Data"]
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    func cellForRowAtIndexPath() -> UITableViewCell {
       var cell = UITableViewCell()
       if (// check for non-nil data here) {
            // configure cell based on loaded data
       }   else {
           cell.textLabel?.text = defaults[indexPath.row]
       }

        return cell
    }
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this. Your question is vague, so I kept my answer similar.

Comment: Ultimately, your question may be less of a how-to inquiry (you can always feed information directly into your UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods), and more of a best practices inquiry. Hard-coded defaults should generally be stored in the VC, or a Constants file, or whatever; don't dump fake data into CoreData, when you can simply check your DB, then use hard-coded entries.