# How should my data be stored? - Swift

Tags: ios

Maybe this is a very basic question, but I have struggled to find a suitable answer. My app will contain a list of fictional characters. Each character has a name, a year of release, a unique ID number, and an accessory/weapon.

The user will not be able to edit, add, or delete characters. There will be about 1500 entries. Each Table View Cell will state the name of the character that when clicked will transition to a View Controller with all of the information.

My question is how do I put this information into my app that then can be used to populate the Table View? I tried using encodable and decodable but that has significantly slowed down my app. I looked into adding the information into a plist, but I still don't know if that is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest core-date, apple has improved it a lot,
If you got 1500 entries today, you may have 3000 entries in near future?

For me one of the strong point is predicates,
also you can link your core-data with your tableview :)

Comment: Sounds like this will work! I have all of my information in a spreadsheet. What is my best way of transferring it into Core Data?

Comment: If your app has a webservice, retrieve it and load it at first launch,
otherwise, here is a solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543825/7722280

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is an option as is a persistent store framework like Realm. The plus side for both of these is query possibilities, and Core Data is probably better if you are comfortable w predicates. Down side for both is dealing with migration hassles when you change your data model.

In your case, if you are just displaying this info read only and don't need strong query, sort capabilities then you could just load this data from a JSON file in your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You could create custom JSON and use it. But @zheck suggested its better if you include a database component to your application. There are multiple reasons to do so.

1. Expandability: Your data might increase over time
2. Flexibility: Format of your data can change
3. Easy to read and easy to write: You may need to update your data

And the list goes on. There are multiple database solutions available  depending on your requirement. While core data is a very strong platform realm, firebase type database solutions give your more flexibility and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use core-data.Core Data manages save and undo functionality for you. It has a persistent store, which tracks changes, and can be flushed to the disk automatically at any number of times.
Core Data and related classes provide easy ways to get your entities into **UITableViews**, like NSFetchedResultsController